# multiple jdk in DOS

Tags: java

I want to test both versions of 64bit java: 1.6 and 1.7. I first installed the 1.6 version and set the java home and path environment variables to it. Then I installed the 1.7 jdk (on a different folder than 1.6), but now I'm seeing this in DOS:

```
C:\Users\jmann>java -version  
java version "1.7.0_25"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Users\jmann>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

C:\Users\jmann>echo %PATH%
c:\software\admin\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
```

if the `PATH` variable is referencing to `1.6/bin..` why does the java -version command is printing the `1.7` version?

Comment: restart command prompt after you made change

Comment: there's usually a java executable in System32 (or one of those system folders) that just directs to what it views as the "best" version of java.. I think it chooses based on the java control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a java executable in any of the other paths preceeding the JDK 1.6.0 path in the PATH variable.